# How can I fill the array of structure randomly?

Tags: c#

My problem is, that the ALL values are changing after iteration.

I wanna that every value in the array till last index, will be different. If use debagger I can see that the code generates everything correct, but I really can not understand why it copies the last result to all objects.

```
public void RandomFillArray(Teacher[] arr, int lastIndex)
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    var temp = new Teacher();
    var posns = new[] {"state", "private"};

    for (var i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++)
    {
        temp._ratePoints = rnd.Next(0, 11);
        temp._expYear = rnd.Next(0, 30);
        temp._position = posns[rnd.Next(0, posns.Length)];
        temp._salary = temp._ratePoints * 1500 + temp._expYear * 500;
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
```

}

If try to print the array it looks like:

```
Rating: 10;    Experience: 6;    Position: private;  Salary: 18000.

Rating: 10;    Experience: 6;    Position: private;  Salary: 18000.

Rating: 10;    Experience: 6;    Position: private;  Salary: 18000.

...
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Move `var temp = new Teacher();` inside the loop

Comment: Just move that temp object into for, because you are creating just one instance of that object.

Comment: As an aside I'd recommend moving `Random` and `string[] posns` outside of the method and mark both of them as `static`. They never going to change and random works better if you create it once.

Answer (score 6):

Its not "copying" anything, the problem is that your `temp` variable is a *reference* to an object and all you're doing us updating the values of that reference.

The easiest solution is just to move `var temp = new Teacher();` into your loop.

Comment: Oh, it was so obvious..

Comment: @Etnim only when you know how ;) We all learned this stuff once upon a time!

Comment: Yeah, everything works now, thanks)

Answer (score 5):

This line is responsible: `arr[i] = temp`

You assign a single instance of teacher to all teachers in the array, so they are the same instance. If you change properties of that instance, you will apply these changes then to all teachers in the array(because they are same).

You need to move the initialization of the instance to the loop body:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++)
{
    var temp = new Teacher();
    temp._ratePoints = rnd.Next(0, 11);
    temp._expYear = rnd.Next(0, 30);
    temp._position = posns[rnd.Next(0, posns.Length)];
    temp._salary = temp._ratePoints * 1500 + temp._expYear * 500;
    arr[i] = temp;
}
```